# CollapsiblePanelExtender - how to make it 4 level nest for navigation

Tags: asp.net

I am using CollapsiblePanelExtender and Panel for menu navigation for my master page. So far, I got it to be two levels nested. How do I expand it to 4 levels deep? Thanks.

```
    <li>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblInbox">Inbox</asp:Label>

        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeInbox" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="pnlInbox"
            CollapseControlID="lblInbox"
            ExpandControlID="lblInbox" />

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlInbox" ScrollBars="None" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <ul>
                <li runat="server" id="liInboxMyCases"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hlInboxMyCases" NavigateUrl="~/Inbox/MyCases.aspx">My Cases</asp:HyperLink></li>
                <li runat="server" id="liInboxAllCases"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hlInboxAllCases" 
                    Visible = <%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("FOIA_Admin")  %>
                    NavigateUrl="~/Inbox/AllCases.aspx?IsAllCases=1">All Cases</asp:HyperLink></li>
                <li runat="server" id="liInboxMyNotifications"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hlInboxMyNotifications" NavigateUrl="~/Inbox/MyNotifications.aspx">My Notifications</asp:HyperLink></li>
                <li runat="server" id="liInboxAllNotifications"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="hlInboxAllNotifications" 
                    Visible = <%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("FOIA_Admin")  %>
                    NavigateUrl="~/Inbox/AllNotifications.aspx?IsAllCases=1">All Notifications</asp:HyperLink></li>
            </ul>
        </asp:Panel>
    </li>
```